# gradle: how to enforce versions of the whole subtree?

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

there is a library `x`. it has a lot of dependencies and dependencies of dependencies. each version of `x` has different tree of dependencies

```
x
|- x1
|  |- ...
|
|- ...
```

in my project some of my other dependencies include `x` with some specific version. some other dependencies include dependencies of `x1`, `x2`, `xk` different versions

what i want to do i to explicitly set version of `x` and enforce all its dependencies to be in a version declared by `x` i chosen

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other path to the dependencies of `x`, then fixing the version of `x` will have that effect.

However, because Gradle does conflict resolution between *all* participants, if a dependency of `x`, let's say `y`, also happens to be a dependency of `z`, which is another dependency of your project, then both version of `y` will be used in conflict resolution.

One way of detecting these issues and thus not being surprised by a conflict resolving an unexpected version is to use the [`failOnVersionConflict` resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:failOnVersionConflict()), as it will fail resolution if two paths bring `y` but with different versions.

Gradle 5.4 and before does not have a built-in mechanism to perform what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [gradle dependency constraints](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:dependency_constraints)?

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    constraints {
        implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3') {
            because 'previous versions have a bug impacting this application'
        }
        implementation('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11') {
            because 'version 1.9 pulled from httpclient has bugs affecting this application'
        }
    }
}
```

You can put the constraints in a common section and then simply declare the dependencies without versions elsewhere.

Comment: yes, but this way i'll have to manually list all dependencies. i'd like to say: all the transitive dependencies of `x` should be in version specified by `x`